# Minimum count of products per order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I need to force one customer group to buy a minimum of 10 products per order (they get free shipping).

Looks to me like this is not possible with normal settings.

Where would I hook in to make this happen?

Would it be easier to use a minimum price instead of product count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::validateMinimumAmount`. This doesn't allow customers to checkout if the order is under a certain amount. You can add your own condition to disallow checkout for orders with less than X products.

Use this if you want the total qty of products to be at least 10.

```
$minQty = 10;
if ($this->getItemsQty() < $minQty){ //$this is instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
    return false;
}
```

or this if you want at least 10 different products in the cart

```
$minQty = 10;
if ($this->getItemsCount() < $minQty){ //$this is instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like `validateMinimumAmount()` is checked while the product is added to the cart. I would need to check the cart contents on `/checkout`.

Comment: Well, that works if I rewrite OnepageController. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller